# Unable to scrape data from json page using Python

Tags: python, json, ajax, web-scraping

I'm trying to pull information off of [this web page](http://financials.morningstar.com/finan/financials/getFinancePart.html?&callback=jsonp1653673850875&t=XNAS:AAPL&region=usa&culture=en-US&cur=&order=asc&_=1653673850919) (Which is providing an AJAX call to [this page](http://financials.morningstar.com/ratios/r.html?t=AAPL)).

I'm able to print out the whole page, but the find_all function just returns a blank list. What am I doing wrong?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "http://financials.morningstar.com/finan/financials/getFinancePart.html?&callback=jsonp1653673850875&t=XNAS:AAPL&region=usa&culture=en-US&cur=&order=asc&_=1653673850919"

def pageText():
    result = requests.get(url)
    doc = BeautifulSoup(result.text, "html.parser")
    return doc


specialNum = pageText()
print(specialNum) 
specialNum = pageText().find_all('literally anything I am trying to pull off of the page')
print(specialNum) #This will always print a blank list
```

Apologies if this is a stupid question. I'm a bit of a beginner.

Answer (score 2):

### EDIT

as mentioned by **@furas** removing parameter and value `callback=jsonp1653673850875` from url server will send pure JSON and you can get HTML directly via `r.json()['componentData']`.

---

Simplest approach in my opinion is to unwrap the JSON string and convert it with `json.loads()` to access the HTML.

From there you can go with `beautifulsoup` or `pandas` to scrape the content.

###### Example beautifulsoup

```
import json, requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('http://financials.morningstar.com/finan/financials/getFinancePart.html?&callback=jsonp1653673850875&t=XNAS:AAPL&region=usa&culture=en-US&cur=&order=asc&_=1653673850919')

soup = BeautifulSoup(
                    json.loads(
                        r.text.split('(',1)[-1].rsplit(')',1)[0]
                    )['componentData']
                )

for row in soup.select('table tr'):
    ...
```

###### Example pandas

```
import json, requests
import pandas as pd

r = requests.get('http://financials.morningstar.com/finan/financials/getFinancePart.html?&callback=jsonp1653673850875&t=XNAS:AAPL&region=usa&culture=en-US&cur=&order=asc&_=1653673850919')

pd.read_html(json.loads(
                        r.text.split('(',1)[-1].rsplit(')',1)[0]
                    )['componentData']
            )[0].dropna()
```

###### Output

| Unnamed: 0 | 2012-09 | 2013-09 | 2014-09 | 2015-09 | 2016-09 | 2017-09 | 2018-09 | 2019-09 | 2020-09 | 2021-09 | TTM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Revenue USD Mil | 156508 | 170910 | 182795 | 233715 | 215639 | 229234 | 265595 | 260174 | 274515 | 365817 | 386017 |
| Gross Margin % | 43.9 | 37.6 | 38.6 | 40.1 | 39.1 | 38.5 | 38.3 | 37.8 | 38.2 | 41.8 | 43.3 |
| Operating Income USD Mil | 55241 | 48999 | 52503 | 71230 | 60024 | 61344 | 70898 | 63930 | 66288 | 108949 | 119379 |
| Operating Margin % | 35.3 | 28.7 | 28.7 | 30.5 | 27.8 | 26.8 | 26.7 | 24.6 | 24.1 | 29.8 | 30.9 |
| Net Income USD Mil | 41733 | 37037 | 39510 | 53394 | 45687 | 48351 | 59531 | 55256 | 57411 | 94680 | 101935 |
| Earnings Per Share USD | 1.58 | 1.42 | 1.61 | 2.31 | 2.08 | 2.3 | 2.98 | 2.97 | 3.28 | 5.61 | 6.15 |
| Dividends USD | 0.09 | 0.41 | 0.45 | 0.49 | 0.55 | 0.6 | 0.68 | 0.75 | 0.8 | 0.85 | 0.88 |
| Payout Ratio % * | — | 27.4 | 28.5 | 22.3 | 24.8 | 26.5 | 23.7 | 25.1 | 23.7 | 16.3 | 14.3 |
| Shares Mil | 26470 | 26087 | 24491 | 23172 | 22001 | 21007 | 20000 | 18596 | 17528 | 16865 | 16585 |
| Book Value Per Share * USD | 4.25 | 4.9 | 5.15 | 5.63 | 5.93 | 6.46 | 6.04 | 5.43 | 4.26 | 3.91 | 4.16 |
| Operating Cash Flow USD Mil | 50856 | 53666 | 59713 | 81266 | 65824 | 63598 | 77434 | 69391 | 80674 | 104038 | 116426 |
| Cap Spending USD Mil | -9402 | -9076 | -9813 | -11488 | -13548 | -12795 | -13313 | -10495 | -7309 | -11085 | -10633 |
| Free Cash Flow USD Mil | 41454 | 44590 | 49900 | 69778 | 52276 | 50803 | 64121 | 58896 | 73365 | 92953 | 105793 |
| Free Cash Flow Per Share * USD | 1.58 | 1.61 | 1.93 | 2.96 | 2.24 | 2.41 | 2.88 | 3.07 | 4.04 | 5.57 | — |
| Working Capital USD Mil | 19111 | 29628 | 5083 | 8768 | 27863 | 27831 | 14473 | 57101 | 38321 | 9355 | — |

Comment: if you remove `callback=jsonp1653673850875` from url then server will send pure JSON and you can get directly `r.json()`

Comment: Wow, I had not considered this approach yet, started the day directly with learning effect. Revised answer and showed your approach additively. Thanks

Comment: Could you explain what's happening on your 8th and 9th line of code? r.text.split('(',1)[-1].rsplit(')',1)[0]
                    )['componentData'] ---- I know what a split is. But I'm unfamiliar with what's happening here.

Comment: This line is unwrapping the JSON  `jsonp1653673850875(JSON)` so `split('(',1)` will split by the first occurence of `(` the last index `[-1]` will looks like `JSON)`.  With `rsplit(')',1)` we split by the first `)` from the right, get rid of it and ends with JSON-String only.